# Loop through each slicer item AND save workbook as xls with file name equal to slicer item selected?

Tags: excel, vba

I just started a new job that is heavily reliant on excel with no other automation tools. I am trying to write a VBA script to loop through each slicer item AND save as xls with file name equal to YYYY-MM & the current slicer item selected. Once one is complete keep going through the slicer items list till all 300 Xls files have been generated with their unique file names. Currently, I am manually doing this for 300 branches to produce month-end reporting and it takes days to do and puts my brain in a vegetated state. I am new to VBA and trying to learn as much as possible soon so any help is greatly appreciated till I am a little more advanced. Kyle

```
Sub SlicerItemsLoop()
    Dim slItem As SlicerItem, slDummy As SlicerItem
    Dim slBox As SlicerCache

    Set slBox = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Division_Code")

    'loop through each slicer item
    For Each slItem In slBox.SlicerItems
        If slItem.HasData Then
            'show all items to start
            slBox.ClearManualFilter

            'test each item against itself
            For Each slDummy In slBox.SlicerItems
                'if the item equals the item in the first loop, then select it
                'otherwise don't show it (thus showing 1 at a time between the nested loops)
                If slItem.Name = slDummy.Name Then slDummy.Selected = True Else: slDummy.Selected = False

                Range("b1") = sI.Name
                'Save to its own file by slicer name
                'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Margin Files\YYYY-MM Month End - &Range("b1").Text &".xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            Next slDummy 
        Else 'do nothing
        End If
    Next slItem
End Sub
```

Comment: I should add that currently, it is breaking at 'For Each slItem In slBox.SlicerItems' with error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: This seems to be working fine until `Range("b1") = sI.Name` where `sI` isn't defined. So not sure why it would do this. Did you try putting a breakpoint on the row that throws an error and inspecting the variables in question?